# Find the domain of function and check if it is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Given the sequence of continuous partial sums $S_n(x)$, which are defined on the interval $[0, 1]$ and  the partial sums uniformly converge to $S(x)$.

Let's denote $f(n, x) := S_n(x)$.

What is the domain of $f_n(x)$ and is it a continuous function?

I don't understand how to check the continuity, since the first argument is a natural number, so it doesn't not make any sense to write $n \to n_0$ in the expression $\lim \limits_{(n \to n_0,\ x \to x0)}f(n, x)$.

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{N} \times [0,1]$. Are you familiar with the topology of $\mathbb{N}$ and the topology of a product?

Also, are you familiar with the open set definition of continuity?

Comment: @wckronholm Yes, I'm familiar with the theorem that you are using in order to show $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @wckronholm So basically, if I have some problem that involves function with two variables, then considering a cartesian product and some theorems from topology is always an option?

Comment: Yes. A function with two variables is implicitly a function $f \colon X \times Y \to Z$ for some domain $X \times Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming your $S$ functions are real-valued.)

In general, a function is continuous is the pre-image of every open set is open.

$\mathbb{N}$ is a discrete topological space, so all subsets are open.

In the product $\mathbb{N} \times [0,1]$, open sets are unions of open sets $U \times V$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{N}$ and $V$ is open in $[0,1]$.

Strategy:
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. Determine $f^{-1}(A)$ and determine if it is an open set.